# FactoryGirl with belongs_to / has_many association with minimum of 1 association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The issue I'm having is specific to a relationship with a belongs_to and has_many where the has_many relationship **has a requirement of at least one association**.  This requirement is causing my Factories to fail my model level validation and not be created.

My Group model

```
Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations, dependent: nullify
  # commenting out the following line will make the tests pass
  validates :organizations, presence: true
  ...
end
```

The Organization model

```
Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  ...
end
```

Organization Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization
    name "test organization"
  end
end
```

And finally the problem child:
Group Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    name "test group"
    after(:create) do |group|
      create(:organization, group: group)
    end
  end
end
```

and in my test, I declare the factory instance:

```
describe "something happens with a Group" do
  let(:group) { FactoryGirl.create :group }

  it "should work" do
    ...
  end
end
```

The errors my tests return are varied, but generally all point to FactoryGirl being unable to create an instance of the `Group` factory.  e.g.

```
# when a test relies on creating an instance of 'Group'
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: Organizations can't be blank
```

The method I'm using (callback) to create my Group factory is from this Thoughtbot post https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl

There are many similar posts, but all of them that I've found as well as the Thoughtbot documentation don't mention this specific use case.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    name 'test group'
    organizations { [association(:organization)] }
  end
end
```

The main idea is to build the needed objects before saving them. You may also try `build_list` if you need more.

Comment: Ahh!  That worked!  Wow, I tired a bunch of variations on this theme, but my syntax was wrong.  Amazing, thank you!